# Fork a file within a Git repository

Tags: git

I'm working on an R project which currently has the following directory layout:

```
proj1
  |-- file.r
```

`file.r` is used to build a statistical model specific to Project 1 (hence `proj1`).

During the course of development, we will be building numerous models for numerous projects:

```
Work
  |-- proj1
  |     └-- file.r
  |-- proj2
  |     └-- file.r
  :
  └-- projn
        └-- file.r
```

`file.r` will be 90% similar between each of the projects, but there will be differences. My question is, **is there a way to create a master `file.r` file and simply fork it for each project?** That way, a bugfix/enhancement to the master can simply be rebased down to the forks, and the file-specific changes will be simply applied on top. My first thought was to use submodules, but I'm not certain how to apply that here. Thanks!

Comment: Normally what you'd do is have the individual project directories be separate repositories (which can be forks of one another).

Answer (score 3):

Use a "topic branch" for each project:

```
git checkout master
git add file.r ;# this is your master template upon which others are based
git commit -m "Committed the master file"
```

Then for each project:

```
git checkout -B <project> master ;# create and checkout <project> branch
<hack away on file.r, commit when you want>
git push origin <project> ;# to share <project> with others
```

So in practice you end up with `master`, upon which, say, `project1`, `project2`, `project3` and so forth are based. Should do exactly what you want and keep it all quite sane.

Advantages of this solution over others that encourage multiple repositories:

1. Easier to manage. You've only got one repository that in practice has, what, 20-30 branches at most? Sounds like a lot, but with clear labels its simple to know where you are, particularly if you're only managing a small file set.
2. Easy diffs if you're lazy (as I am). You can see the differences in the file between two projects' `file.r` with `git diff projectA projectB -- file.r`. You could do the same with multiple repositories, but it requires a repository specification like `git diff projectA/master projectB/master -- file.r`. Could get confusing if you have 20-30 project repositories or use submodules.
3. Easy updates. Grabbing updates is as simple as issuing `git fetch origin` and watching the output.
4. Easy clones. When setting up a new local repo, you clone a single remote. No need to clone origin, then `git remote add <project>` repositories until you've got them all.

Disadvantages (an incomplete list):

1. This method relies on you paying close attention to your checked out branch. Nothing about the directory structure will clue you in, so it might not be as obvious what `file.r` you're viewing at any given moment. That might be a deal breaker. I dunno. I suppose it depends on your workflow.
2. As KurzedMetal points out in comments, this could get messy fast if you ever need to merge all the projects into one. As such, I wouldn't recommend it for source code. For distinct `R` projects, however, this might be less of a concern.

Comment: Actually, you could just have a specific `README-ProjX.txt` in each repo, where `X` is the project number, so that it's immediately visible on changing branches which is being used.

Comment: Not a bad way to do it. If the total number of managed files is small, this should work pretty well in practice.

Comment: 2nd disadvantage: your project history will be a mess (by merging all of them), and you'll end up needed to `git filter-branch` (which is very risky) if you ever need to split them or if you don't want to give access to all devs to all projects.

Comment: @KruzedMetal - I worked from the assumption they'd never need to merge them, but yes that's true. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

IMO the best way to achieve this is:

1. create a library and a repo of your shared code
2. create a repo for each project
3. use `git submodule` to integrate the shared code to each project
4. import the r library and add the project specific code.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways described in the other answers.

For example,

- use object-oriented-patterns or templates to increase reuse and reduce code.
- use git branch
- use git submodule
- Finally, when no other way, **I use comments in the file header, that it is a fork of another file.**

  ```
   Date          | Author              | Description
   ------------- | ------------------- | --------------
   05/18/2018    | You                 | Forked from Other/file.r
  ```